# OS X Keychain access lost on updates

Tags: macos, code-signing, keychain

My app is using the Keychain access to store passwords. It works fine.

But once I update the application, I lose access to the previously stored passwords. The user needs to unlock it again. Also, the user is unable to delete his password even if he allows the app to use the password with the Keychain dialog.

Does this have to do with my bundle-indentifier / version ? Can I fix it with code signing ?

Any help welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code signing is the correct way to fix this. The keychain uses the signature to verify that this is the "same" program, even though its contents have changed, based on it having a matching signature.  I'm not certain exactly, but I think the basic requirement is that the signing entity be the same, and that the bundle ID match. See [Apple's code signing guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/AboutCS/AboutCS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005929-CH3-SW4) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I couldn't find documentation about how the Keychain checks it's the same app. If anyone knows something more about it, I would be glad to hear it.